# TLS version on apache HttpClient

Tags: java, rest, ssl, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using apache **httpclient 4.5.2** to call a target server that support TLSv1.1

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

If the target server will no longer support TLSv1.1 and move to support TLSv1.2 do I need change the way i create my HttpClient?

If I did not set the TLS version until today, do I need to change my code when the server is moving to TLSv1.2?

Comment: maybe it is duplicate but if i did not set the TLS version until today, do i need to change my code when the server is moving to TLSv1.2

Comment: It depends on your Java version, not on the Apache `HTTPClient`. If your Java version supports TLS 1.2 there is nothing to do, and if it doesn't you need to upgrade your Java. No code changes required.

Comment: i'm using java 1.8

Comment: So you don't have a problem. [Java 1.8 supports TLSv1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).

Comment: tnx a lot @user207421